# I am trying to display an item in my store array

Tags: java, arrays

**I am trying to display an item the user is looking for which works but the else statement prints multiple times as well 
for example if I entered pens I get this:

---

Here you can search for products:
Please enter what you are looking for:
pens
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
Here is the item:                 Pens       School Supplies                   $2.00
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
We don't have that item, or check your spelling
Want to look for something else or try again? Enter 1, if not enter 0. What will be your choice:

**Please help me figure it out I have been stuck here for a while.
I have provided the code at the bottom.

```
public static void findProducts(String[][] store) {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 1;
    do {
    System.out.print("Please enter what you are looking for: ");
    String search = user_input.next();
    for (int row = 0; row < store.length; row++) {
        String rowOutput = "";
        for (int column = 0; column < store[row].length; column++)
        {
            rowOutput += String.format("%20s\t",store[row][column]);
        }
        if (store[row][0].toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("Here is the item: " + rowOutput);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("We don't have that item, or check your"
                    + " spelling");

        }
    }
        System.out.print("Want to look for something else or try"
                + " again? Enter 1, if"
                + " not enter 0. What wiil be your choice: ");
     choice = user_input.nextInt();
    } while(choice != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you're going through the if-else for every entry in the array. So one of the entries is pens, but all the others will get sent to the else clause. You need to separate that from the for loop. Something like:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int row = 0; row < store.length; row++) {
    if (store[row][0].toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase())) {
        found = true;
    }
}
if (found) {
    System.out.println("Item found");
}
else {
    System.out.println("We don't have that item, or check your"
            + " spelling");
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `store[row][0]` is likely also an error.  I doubt he meant to check only the first element.

Comment: I was assuming the column held store information, so we are looking through all the rows of store 0, which the for loop will do.

Comment: Thanks Ryan and Don Scott for the help I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly obvious error.  Here is the breakdown:

1. **You get the input:**

   ```
   String search = user_input.next();
   ```
2. **For every store:**

   ```
   for (int row = 0; row < store.length; row++) {
   ```

   3. **If the first item in that store does not match...**

      ```
      if (store[row][0].toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase())) {
      ```
   4. **Print...**

      ```
      System.out.println("We don't have that item, or check your spelling");
      ```